# A question about an affirmation on page 128 of the book Analysis on Lie groups, by James Faurat.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, diagonalization

In the page 128, of the book Analysis on Lie groups by James Faurat, we have the following paragraph:

Every element $x\in SU(2)$ is conjugate to a diagonal matrix of the form

$a(\theta) = \exp(\theta X_{1})$
= $\begin{pmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\theta} \end{pmatrix}$

that is, $x = ga(\theta)g^{-1}$ with $g\in SU(2)$, $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. In fact a unitary matrix $x$ is normal: $x^{*}x = xx^{*}$, hence diagonalisable in an ortogonal basis. This means that

$x$ = 
$g
\begin{pmatrix} e^{i\theta_{1}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\theta_{2}} \end{pmatrix} g^{-1}$,
$\,\,\,\,(g\in U(2),\,\, \theta_{1}, \theta_{2}\in\mathbb{R})$

One can choose $g$ with determinant equal to one and, since $\det(x) =1$, one can choose $\theta_{2} = -\theta_{1}$:

$x$ = 
$g
\begin{pmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\theta} \end{pmatrix} g^{-1}$,
$\,\,\,\,(g\in SU(2),\,\, \theta\in\mathbb{R})$

**Question**:

Why can we choose $g\in SU(2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every unitary matrix is normal and the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Normal_matrices) says that if $M$ is normal, then there is an unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{-1}MU$ is diagonal. Now, let $\Delta=\det U$ and let $\omega$ be a square root of $\Delta$. Then $\frac1\omega U$ will also work and $\frac1\omega U\in SU(2)$.

This works for $n\times n$ complex matrices (take a $n$<sup>th</sup> root of $\Delta$ in this case).

Comment: I understand why we can take  g in U(2) , but what I do not understand is why later we can take  g  in SU(2) . :(

Comment: @JoséHernandez I have edited my answer. I hope that all is well now.

Comment: It is clear to me that the determinant of (1 / w) (U) is 1 but when multiplying (1 / w) (U) by its conjugate transpose I do not obtain the identity matrix :(.

Comment: I suppose that you agree that $U^*U=\operatorname{Id}$. Besides, $|\omega|=1$. Therefore$$\left(\frac1\omega U\right)^*\left(\frac1\omega U\right)=\frac1{\overline\omega}\cdot\frac1\omega U^*U=\frac1{|\omega|^2}\operatorname{Id}=\operatorname{Id}.$$

Comment: I had done exactly the same operation but I was not sure if the w module was one, but I saw why that is true, thank you very much :).